# testing ruby on rails application using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

`rspec spec/models/contact_spec.rb` ==> While running this code in my terminal, I receive the following error message: `uninitialized constant Factory.`

```
# spec/factories/contacts.rb
=============================================
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do |f|
    f.firstname { Faker::Name.first_name }
    f.lastname { Faker::Name.last_name }
  end
end
=============================================

# spec/models/contact_spec.rb
=============================================
require 'spec_helper'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
describe Contact do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    Factory.create(:contact).should be_valid
  end
  it "is invalid without a firstname"
  it "is invalid without a lastname"
  it "returns a contact's full name as a string"
end
=============================================
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Try `FactoryGirl.create(:contact)` instead of `Factory.create(:contact)`; the `Factory` shortcut may not be configured on your app.

Comment: Awesome. Will add the same as an answer so that it helps others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `FactoryGirl.create(:contact)` instead of `Factory.create(:contact)`; the Factory shortcut may not be configured on your app.